# ASP.NET RESTful Simple Secure Authentication Pattern

Tags: web-services, authentication, design-patterns, restful-authentication

I want to create a simple web service authorize module.  Don’t want to use 3rd party authorizing component.  I’m thinking to set it up like this.  Let’s say Client want to call the Foo() API on the server.

- Client – Connect with Server Credentials (basic authentication to IIS over SSL) → Server
- If successful (else exit)
- Client – Call Login(credentials) API (login to the system) → Server
- If Successful (else empty string or something like that)
- Server – Session ID or token (expire with in a period) → Client
- Client – Call Foo(sessionID/token) (call APIs with Session ID) → Server

I know there should a component that does this authentication, but I rather use .NET Framework built in components, (don’t want to use 3rd party components.)  If you know any let me know.  Is this a valid pattern, I'm user someone has done this before.  Do you think I should use Session ID to send back, or send back some kind of Guid or token?